# How to retain the selected colour of a button until another button in that group is selected only in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, events

I have ran into an interesting problem. I have seen half the solution elsewhere but I have not come across the complete solution.

So here is my game where I am developing a complex UI. The main screen has 5 buttons in the bottom navigation bar and respective screens to called when clicked. So when any of the buttons is clicked the selected colour i.e., green in my case is seen and things are fine till now.

But when I click on any part of the screen the selected colour disappears and I don't want that to happen.

I found a solution [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1362254/how-to-keep-a-ui-button-stay-highlighted-or-at-lea.html#:%7E:text=It%27s%20an%20old%20question%20but%20in%20case%20someone%20is%20looking%20for%20the%20answer%2C%20I%20wrote%20this%20simple%20script%20to%20keep%20the%20last%20selected%20game%20object%20selected%20at%20all%20times.%20Just%20add%20this%20to%20your%20EventSystem%20object.) and it works but I have another problem here. In for example the Home Screen of my Home tab there are several other buttons like "Buy Coins",etc and when I click on those buttons the selected colour disappears. When I click on any other part of the screen the selected colour is there, but if I select on any button element of the screen the selected colour disappears.

I tried adding the toggle element for the button but Unity doesn't allow me to do.

So how do I fix this problem?

<-----------EDIT--------->

The code is like this:

```
public void OnClickBottomNavigationButton(GameObject activeScreen)//executed when any of the bottom naviagtion button is clicked
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Screens.Length; i++)
        {
            Screens[i].SetActive(false);
        }
        activeScreen.SetActive(true);//after setting all to false , the required screen which is passed when the button is clicked is set to true
    }
```

So this script is attached to the object which has a horizontal component attached it whose children are the buttons. So when any of the buttons is pressed , the required screen Gameobject is passed to make the selection possible

Comment: you can try to merge these: 1. [Get button color](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1426354/get-color-of-button-and-set-to-an-object.html) 2. [Get component in a child of a group](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1084518/how-would-i-access-a-property-of-another-objects-c.html)

Comment: Instead of `Button` use `Toggle` and a [`ToggleGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ToggleGroup.html) (aka "Radio Button" e.g. in web design) => this way only one button "isOn" at a time and you can color it green when active

Comment: @derHugo as I have said towards the end of the answer,I tried adding a toggle element to the button, but Unity doesnt allow that to happen

Comment: you don't **add** a `Toggle` to a `Button` ... you **replace** the `Button` by a `Toggle`

Comment: No I my scenario I need a button only @derHugo

Comment: why though? what can a button do that a toggle can not? Except that the toggle solves exactly the issue you have ^^ You only need to reformat the default toggle slightly, make the background fill the entire button, replace the checkmark texture by the same background texture and make it fill the entire background -> color it green. Finally make the label also fill the entire button => you now have a button that turn green when active an stays green until it is deactivated. Finally the toggle group makes sure only one button is active at a time

Comment: You should show the code, because your problem may not be toggle/button related. You mention that buttons are affected when clicking anywhere, that'd be the first issue to tackle. Having radio toggle system on buttons is fairly simple next if you really did not want to use toggle.

Comment: @Everts u can see the code in the edit section

Comment: @derHugo sure will give it a try